# InflateException exception for 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.1.6'

Tags: android

initially chart is working well but when i added new feature to my application 
getting inflate exception for xml file containing

nothing changed in support library, min sdk

my log is as following

> UncaughtException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start
>   activity
>   ComponentInfo{savvytekmate.dev.com.jaccha_baccha/savvytekmate.dev.com.jaccha_baccha.activities.BlankActivityForFragment}:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error
>   inflating class com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart
>                                                                                            at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
>                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
>                                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
>                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                                            at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
>                                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
>                                                                                         Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13:
>   Error inflating class com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart
>                                                                                            at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:757)
>                                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
>                                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
>                                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
>                                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
>                                                                                            at
>   savvytekmate.dev.com.jaccha_baccha.fragments.parenting_fragment.growth_chart.MonthVsHeadCircumFragment.onCreateView(MonthVsHeadCircumFragment.java:73)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2192)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1299)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1528)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1595)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:758)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2363)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2149)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2103)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2013)
>                                                                                            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performStart(Fragment.java:2214)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1340)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1528)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1595)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStart(FragmentManager.java:2907)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchStart(FragmentController.java:212)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:613)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:178)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1236)
>                                                                                            at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6006)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2288)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
>                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
>                                                                                            at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
>                                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
>                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
>                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>                                                                                            at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
>                                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
>                                                                                         Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart" on path:
>   DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/savvytekmate.dev.com.jaccha_baccha-1/base.apk", zip file
>   "/data/app/savvytekmate.dev.com.jaccha_baccha-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/savvytekmate.dev.com.jaccha_baccha-1/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/savvytekmate.dev.com.jaccha_baccha-1/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/savvytekmate.dev.com.jaccha_baccha-1/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/savvytekmate.dev.com.jaccha_baccha-1/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/savvytekmate.dev.com.jaccha_baccha-1/split_lib_slice_4_apk.
>   09-30 11:04:24.975 8122-8122/savvytekmate.dev.com.jaccha_baccha
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                     Process: savvytekmate.dev.com.jaccha_baccha, PID: 8122
>                                                                                     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{savvytekmate.dev.com.jaccha_baccha/savvytekmate.dev.com.jaccha_baccha.activities.BlankActivityForFragment}:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error
>   inflating class com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart
>                                                                                         at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
>                                                                                         at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
>                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
>                                                                                         at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
>                                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
>                                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                                         at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
>                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
>                                                                                      Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13:
>   Error inflating class com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart
>                                                                                         at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:757)
>                                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
>                                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
>                                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
>                                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
>                                                                                         at
>   savvytekmate.dev.com.jaccha_baccha.fragments.parenting_fragment.growth_chart.MonthVsHeadCircumFragment.onCreateView(MonthVsHeadCircumFragment.java:73)
>                                                                                         at
>   android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2192)
>                                                                                         at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1299)
>                                                                                         at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1528)
>                                                                                         at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1595)
>                                                                                         at
>   android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:758)
>                                                                                         at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2363)
>                                                                                         at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2149)
>                                                                                         at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2103)
>                                                                                         at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2013)
>                                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performStart(Fragment.java:2214)
>                                                                                         at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1340)
>                                                                                         at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1528)
>                                                                                         at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1595)
>                                                                                         at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStart(FragmentManager.java:2907)
>                                                                                         at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchStart(FragmentController.java:212)
>                                                                                         at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:613)
>                                                                                         at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:178)
>                                                                                         at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1236)
>                                                                                         at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6006)
>                                                                                         at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2288)
>                                                                                         at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
>                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
>                                                                                         at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
>                                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
>                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
>                                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>                                                                                         at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
>                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
>                                                                                      Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart" on path:
>   DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/savvytekmate.dev.com.jaccha_baccha-1/base.apk", zip file
>   "/data/app/savvytekmate.dev.com.jaccha_baccha-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/savvytekmate.dev.com.jaccha_baccha-1/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/savvytekmate.dev.com.jaccha_baccha-1/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/savvytekmate.dev.com.jaccha_baccha-1/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/savvytekmate.dev.com.jaccha_baccha-1/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk",
>   zip fi

Comment: Please show your build.gradle file

Comment: @ Nongthonbam Tonthoi  this is my build.gradle

Comment: I can't see it.